# signInWithEmailAndPassword and EmailAuthProvider

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to understand the new authentication model. I am trying to convert web code that used the older authWithPassword.

Considering I had:

```
firebase.authWithPassword({email: email, password: password }).then(
   authData => console.log('auth: authWithPassword success '+authData.uid), 
   err => console.log('auth: authWithPassword fail: '+err));
```

How do I achieve the same thing with the new version ?

There seem to be two different interfaces:

`auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`

and

`firepad.auth.EmailAuthProvider`

but I don't understand the difference or how to use them. Is there any clear example for the correct way to do email authentication ?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password

Comment: thx Frank ! can you please explain the role of EmailAuthProvider and where it should be used ?

Comment: You don't need it to sign in a user, since there is a dedicated method for you to call.

Comment: thx frank ! would be good to post these comments as answers so I can accept them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of such differences with the new API. Best to stick closely to the docs.

The new docs site  has a guide on email/password authentication,  but to your specific question about the code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password

Comment: thx Brandon ! can you please explain the role of EmailAuthProvider and where it should be used ?

Comment: I can't, sorry :\ The new docs are woefully short of where the old docs were, so it's hard to get details like that. The [Firebase mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) is usually pretty helpful if you wanted to try there, though.

Comment: @Brandon The above method is not giving any success method. could you tell me how to take success event using above method ?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the docs, I think EmailAuthProvider is used for re-authentication workflow (before changePass, changeEmail etc.).

Auth.currentUser.reauthenticate(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential('user@example.com', 'existingPassword'));